# Text to columns - issue with commas

Tags: excel, vba, text-to-column

I am trying to seperate my columns with vba.
This is how my data looks:

first row:

```
Time,[CB:01:4A:7D:06:2D] Thermometer_0,[E5:39:8E:7F:E4:11] Thermometer_0,[F1:89:F8:3A:EA:63] Thermometer_0,[F7:C6:4A:56:E4:23] Thermometer_0
```

second row:

```
11/23/2021 10:50,,,,20.9
```

That means that I need to have 11/23/2021 10:50 in the first column (Time), second, third and fourth are empty, and in the fifth value 20.9.
There are variations for the second row.

Currently I am trying with this code:

```
Sub TextToCol3()
   Range("A1:A135").TextToColumns , xlDelimited, xlDoubleQuote, True, , , True, True, True
End Sub
```

But this just ignore the empty spaces between commas, and creates only two columns.

Comment: You should be good to use the named parameters to see where the consecutive Delimiter one appears...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test the next way:

```
Range("A1:A135").TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Comma:=True
```

If `ConsecutiveDelimiter = True`, the consecutive delimiters are considered **as one delimiter**...

Comment: @Ena Didn't the above solution solve your problem?